# Button touches border of toolbar

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

When I dock a button to right in the toolbar, it starts touching the upper border of the toolbar like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyFormPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'Field'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'Field'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'bottom',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        ui: 'back',
                        text: 'Back'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        docked: 'right',
                        ui: 'forward',
                        text: 'Continue'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Comment: can you post your currently code?

Comment: @user1479606 I've added code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have the same problem, but I solved it! You use, just like I did, `xtype: 'toolbar'` to dock your buttons. What you have to use is

`xtype: 'titlebar'`

Now, if you have some buttons in your titlebar, just set the `align` property, like this:

```
 xtype: 'titlebar',
 items: [
      {
         xtype: 'button',
         ui: 'back',
         text: 'Back',
         align: 'left'
      },
      {
         xtype: 'button',
         ui: 'forward',
         text: 'Continue',
         align: 'right'
      }
 ]
```

Check Sencha Docs for more info: [Ext.TitleBar](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.TitleBar)

Answer (score 0):

Same behaviour here, also when instead of docking on the right I use right:10px;.

This is probably caused by the element becoming position:absolute. Don't have a solution that prevents this from happening in the first place, but of course you can correct it by setting top:..px to the button.
If you've got a lot of buttons like this, use a css class to set this.

Answer (score 0):

Same behaviour here, also when instead of docking on the right I use right:10px;.

This is probably caused by the element becoming position:absolute. Don't have a solution that prevents this from happening in the first place, but of course you can correct it by setting top:..px to the button.
If you've got a lot of buttons like this, use a css class to set this.

Please also report this on the [Sencha Touch Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure is there a bug or not but you can try different way by removing your `docked: 'right'`and adding an `xtype: spacer` between your two button like this:

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        ui: 'back',
        text: 'Back'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'spacer'  
    },
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        ui: 'forward',
        text: 'Continue'
    }
]
```

> The Ext.Spacer component is generally used to put space between items
>   in Ext.Toolbar components.

You can find more informations and examples in their docs about `spacer` [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Spacer). Hope it helps :)